# Cannot copy one field to another

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a site that has a checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked it will copy one form value to another. It worked fine until I actually wrapped the fields in the `<form>` tag. Now it no longer copies. Here is what I was using

```
function sameBilling(){
    document.getElementById("billingFirst").value = document.getElementById("mailingFirst").value;  
    document.getElementById("billingLast").value = document.getElementById("mailingLast").value;
    document.getElementById("billingCity").value = document.getElementById("mailingCity").value;
    document.getElementById("billingState").value = document.getElementById("mailingState").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("mailingZip").value;
    document.getElementById("billingAddress").value = document.getElementById("mailingAddress").value;
}
```

form

```
 <form action="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" method="post">
      <table width="840" border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><strong>Shipping Address</strong></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Billing Address</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingFirst">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingFirst" id="mailingFirst" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingFirst")'></td>
          <td align="right">Same Billing Address?
            <input name="sameBilling" id="billingCheck" type="checkbox" value="Same Billing" onClick="sameBilling();"></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingFirst">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingFirst" id="billingFirst" onfocus='remove_errors("billingFirst")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingLast">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingLast" id="mailingLast" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingLast")'></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="product01" id="product01"></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingLast">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingLast" id="billingLast" onfocus='remove_errors("billingLast")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingAddress" id="mailingAddress" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingAddress")'></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="product02" id="product02"></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingAddress" id="billingAddress" onfocus='remove_errors("billingAddress")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingCity" id="mailingCity" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingCity")'></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="product03" id="product03"></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingCity" id="billingCity" onfocus='remove_errors("billingCity")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingState">State</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingState" id="mailingState" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingState")'></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="product04" id="product04"></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingState">State</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingState" id="billingState" onfocus='remove_errors("billingState")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="mailingZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" name="mailingZip" id="mailingZip" onfocus='remove_errors("mailingZip")'></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><label for="billingZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" name="billingZip" id="billingZip" onfocus='remove_errors("billingZip")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="ccNum">CC Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="ccNum" id="ccNum" onfocus='remove_errors("ccNum")'></td>
          <td align="center"><label for="ccExp">CC Expiration</label>
            <input type="text" name="ccExp" id="ccExp" onfocus='remove_errors("ccExp")'></td>
          <td align="right"><label for="ccType">CC Type</label>
            <input type="text" name="ccType" id="ccType" onfocus='remove_errors("ccType")'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: I added the . I was missing. Sorry that was not the problem

Comment: there is a lot of HTML, is it really necessary? This code worked until I wrapped the fields in the <form> tag. Does wrapping it in a form tag have anything to do with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  We can't help without seeing the HTML to see where the problem might be.  Are your ids unique in the page (only one element with a given id)?  Are there any javascript errors being reported in the error console or debug console?  Are you sure this line of code is actually executing?

Comment: I added the function and the form. That is all that is used in the problem

Comment: So you're saying if you take all of the (latest version) of the above and simply remove the opening `<form>` and closing `</form>` tags it will then work? Because really that should make no difference at all. Like jfriend00 asked, are you getting any errors in your browser's error/debug console?

Comment: actually I gave the form a name and used this:document.theForm.elements["billingFirst"].value = document.theForm.elements["mailingFirst"].value; and it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the form `name="theForm"` and changed the lines in the function to

```
document.theForm.elements["billingFirst"].value = document.theForm.elements["mailingFirst"].value;
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `.` in `documentgetElementById` - change to `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Sorry the dot is there I must have removed it when I pasted and formatted

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think the problem (in IE, anyway) is that your function name `sameBilling()` is the same as the checkbox input `name="sameBilling"`. When I copied your HTML and JS code to test it out for myself the only change I had to make to get it to work was to rename the function or rename the input.

IE does this thing where element names and ids are treated as if they were global variables, and so it gets confused if you have your own variables or functions with the same name. (Some other browsers have the same problem because they have tried to be consistent with what IE does.)

(Having said that, it doesn't explain why your fix to stop using `.getElementById()` would work.)

<s>The `.getElementById()` method belongs to the `document` object, like so:</s>

```
document.getElementById("someId")
```

It doesn't matter where on the page the element with id="someId" is or whether that element is a child of a form element because id is supposed to be unique on the page.

So your code doesn't work because you are trying to use `.getElementById()` on a form element:

```
document.forms[0].getElementById("billingFirst").value = ...
//       ^^^^^^^^^ - remove the "forms[0]." part
```

You should change it to:

```
document.getElementById("billingFirst").value =
                          document.getElementById("mailingFirst").value;
// etc
```

Comment: Sorry this was my second try. I originally uploaded without the forms[0] approach but they wanted me to upload more code and I left it on there. It doesnt work without the forms

Comment: They are not both called billingFirst. The checkbox is called billingCheck

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my post. The name of the function and the name attribute of the checkbox are both "sameBilling". I've updated my answer.